# How can I resize an image before to upload to firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, blob

I have files to upload to `firebase` from `reactjs`.
The files are likes this: they have a lot of properties:

```
[File {path: 'image1.jpg', index: 0, fName: 'imageBall1.jpg', type: 'jpg', …},
 File {path: 'image2.jpg', index: 1, fName: 'imageBall2.jpg', type: 'jpg', …}]
```

I want to resize before to upload, so I did this code

```
export const resizeFile = async imageFiles => {
  return await imageFiles.map(async file => {
    const a =  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      file,
      300,
      300,
      "JPEG",
      100,
      0,
      (uri) => {
        resolve(uri);
      },
      "base64"
    );
    });
    console.log('file', file, a)
    return a
  })
}
```

But I am getting this result:

```
Blob data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDAAABoAAAAChnVFJDAAABoAAAAChiVFJDAAAB
```

That I can not upload to `firebase`, how can I resize an image to upload to `firebase`? or should I convert that binary to image again?

**I would rather upload in image not in binary**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` in your base64 string. And then you use
`.putString(image, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpg'});` to upload into firebase.

Make sure that you have `{contentType:'image/jpg'}` to let firebase know file type.

You can find out more here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string

Comment: How can I convert that binary to image again?

Comment: @brunodia You append it again like this. `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,uploaded_base64_string_into_firebase"/>`

Comment: @Tartarius can i convert to image before to upload?

Comment: @brunodia basically, you can't do it on reactjs/browser/frontend. If you still want to convert the base64 string to an image file again, you should do it on your server/backend before you upload it into firebase.

Comment: Is the compression that I did to reduce the size of the image ok? is there a better way to do it without convert to binaries?

Comment: @brunodia I suggest that you should move the compression into the server/backend also if you want to convert it into an image.  You can find another compression library that can output into a file directly. Anyway, the best solution is still to upload it into firebase directly by using `putString`.

Comment: Could you add an example to your answer please, I think I will need to regex to delete this part "data: image / jpeg; base64,"? put  an functional example please

Comment: @brunodia just simple `var removedResult = base64string.split("base64,")[1];`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a base-64 encoded binary representation of the jpg. This is usually fine to send to the server. Image files, like all files, are just binary files with certain filenames or special headers that signal how consuming applications should use them. Plenty of applications, including web browsers can consume base-64 encoded images. See [here for an example of how to render a base-64 string as an image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML). I believe if you store a new file in firebase where the contents is your base-64 string, you will be able to use the resulting file like any other image. Firebase even has [an example](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/2b9c3212d3844d394f8d98f30cadc03fdef8c2f5/snippets/storage-next/upload-files/storage_upload_string.js#L19-L23) of uploading a base-64 string in [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#web-version-9_3).

Comment: How can I convert that binary to image again? before to upload